# How to recover from a corrupted glibc on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: server, 20.04, glibc

Given a second chance I would double check it, but I accidentally run `sudo ln -sf something /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so`. And there is not another copy of glibc because this is the real shared object instead of a symlink.

So how can I recover from it? I think I may have to get another copy glibc, boot the machine from a usb device, and copy the clean `libc-2.31.so` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

What is the correct way to do it? Do I also have to rebuild the symlinks `libc.so.6` under `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not create symlinks in the folders which are controlled by APT!!!

You will break the system and/or create a nightmare for its future maintenance!!!**

To recover the situation reinstall the [libc6 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libc-2.31.so) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6
```

and do not touch symlinks next time.
**If you want to play with the system - do this in `/usr/local/bin` which is outside of APT control.**

---

Note: on the fresh minimal 20.04 LTS there is only one file named *libc-2.31.so* - see

> ```
> # find / -name libc-2.31.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
> ```

and one named *libc.so.6*:

> ```
>  # find / -name libc.so.6
>  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
> ```

while they are symlinked as follows (central part is replaced by `(...)`):

> ```
>  # ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>  -rwxr-xr-x (...) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
>  lrwxrwxrwx (...) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.31.so
> ```

Both [are provided](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/libc6/filelist) by `libc6` [deb-package](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb).

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear, but the server is currently down and cannot boot again because it says it cannot find `libc.so.6`. If I run the command in the bootable USB, it does not seem to install glibc on the original disk of the server, right?

Comment: Then you have to boot using live-USB, mount rootfs of the server filesystem, chroot to it and reinstall the `libc6` package there. Or copy both `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so` from live system to server fs, then reboot to the OS and reinstall the latest `libc6` deb-package.

Comment: Thanks for your fast clarification! I run `find / -name libc-2.31.so` on a fresh live system, and get the same result as you. But when I run `ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libc`, there is still `libc-2.31` and `libc.so.6`...

Comment: I had a typo in previous comment. Thanks! I edited an answer to clarify this moment about symlinks between libc-2.31 and libc.so.6. I think it is now complete and you can accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed advice! I'm still on my way to touch the server and would update the question if things don't work well.

Comment: I hope all will be going well. Be careful next time :)

Comment: fwiw, on my 22.04 ubuntu, my `libresolv.so` (a file also installed by `libc6*.deb`) recently somehow became corrupted (result: couldn't boot, *but* I *could* boot into recovery mode, but no internet). So to fix, I downloaded the deb package from a "live USB" to local disk, and then rebooted into "recovery" mode, and re-installed the package via `dpkg -i ./path/to/libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb` (make sure to get correct pkg for your release). This _might_ also work in the situation described here, _assuming_ you can boot into recovery mode https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode